# chessboard.js can't play a game with a set position

Tags: php, chessboard.js

When I use the example 'only allow legal moves http://chessboardjs.com/examples#5000, I can move the white and black pieces.
When I want to set a fen string in the config, replacing `position: 'start'` by `position: 'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R'`, I can't move the pieces that have already been moved and if I move a piece that has never been moved, all the other pieces get back to the start position.

Comment: Any particular reason why you've tagged this question `php`?

Comment: I'am using it in a wordpress website.

Comment: About as relevant as saying you're running an nginx webserver, or that it's hosted in Indonesia.... chessboard.js doesn't care about any of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R'** is not valid FEN format for chess.js because the library doesn't know about any parameters (move: black or white, castles, e.t.c).

```
var game = new Chess();
game.validate_fen('r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R');

//Object {valid: false, error_number: 1, error: "FEN string must contain six space-delimited fields."}
```

You should use correct FEN for chess.js. For example:

```
var game = new Chess("rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq e3 0 2");

// cfg.position == "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq e3 0 2"
```

Or you can use **game.load** function. For example:

```
var game = new Chess();
game.load("rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq e3 0 2");

// cfg.position == "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq e3 0 2"
```

Comment: So how can we convert `r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R` to valid chess.js fen? Coz we need that position of the board to start playing.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your FEN string it isn't made up of 6 space delimited sections like the one below, which is valid. You only have the first bit in yours.

```
"rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq e3 0 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R' this is only a part of FEN.

Example of valid FEN for chess.js:

> "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2"

In the examples above, "-" is missing. It didn't work for me without it.